# About the differentiability of $|x|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The derivative of a function is another function which gives the slope of the tangent line at a certain point of the function. And then, taking $f(x)=|x|$, I'd have:

$$[f(x)]'=\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^2}-\sqrt{x^2}}{h}=\frac{(x+h)-x}{h}=\frac{h}{h}=1$$

Then that should be the function that would indicate the slope of $f(x)=|x|$, it works when $x>0$ because the slope is $1$ but fails when $x<0$ because the slope is $-1$ and then, I guess that the *need* to have two different derivatives for one function indicates that some point might be *broken*.

The problem here is that it's actually possible to express the derivative of that function with only one function: $f'(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$, the problem is that this new function is discontinuous at $f(0)$. I am starting to guess that for a function to be differentiable at a point, all it's derivatives should also be continuous at the same point. Is my guess correct?

Comment: Your derivation is not correct: $\sqrt{(x+h)^2}$ is not equal to $x+h$, it is $|x+h|$. The same goes for $\sqrt{x^2}$ (which you've mistyped as $\sqrt x$, by the way).

Comment: Regarding your last question: no, $|x|$ is continuous everywhere but its derivative does not exist at $0$.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the difference quotient, btw.

Comment: You computed the derivative of $x$, not that of $|x|$.

Comment: It's much easier to try to differentiate this function if you think of it as $f(x)=\pm x$, with the sign depending on the domain interval in which $x$ lies. Then you can easily see that the function is differentiable away from $0$ (because it coincides with linear functions on those parts of the domain), and not differentiable at $0$ because the result depends on the direction of approach (i.e., whether $h\to 0^+$ or $h\to 0^-$).

Comment: @Rahul Isn't $|x|$ sometimes defined as $\sqrt{x^2}$?

Comment: There are functions which are continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.

Comment: The problem with what you wrote is that it is NOT TRUE that $\sqrt{(x+h)^2} = (x+h)$. That's only true if $(x+h)$ is positive. Otherwise, it's...well...$|x+h|$.

Comment: I made a silly mistake, my impression was actually: *I am starting to guess that for a function to be differentiable at a point, all it's derivatives should also be continuous at the same point.*

Answer (score 3):

No, a function doesn't even need to be differentiable to be continuous, like in this case: clearly $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous in the whole real line, but it isn't differentiable in the origin.

Your incremental ratio is wrong, by the way: the limit operator is missing (or else, that is *not* the derivative), and $\sqrt{(x+h)^2}=x+h$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ only for $x,x+h\geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, it's actually: *I am starting to guess that for a function to be differentiable at a point, all it's derivatives should also be continuous at the same point.*

Comment: Do you mean that every higher order derivative has to be continuous?

Comment: Exactly. I was a little bit lazy when typing, sorry.

Comment: This is false anyway. Take $f:\ \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=-x^2$ if $x<0$, and $f(x)=x^2$ if $x\geq 0$. You can see that it is differentiable in every point of the real line, but $f'(x)=|x|$ that isn't differentiable in $x=0$, so higher order derivatives don't even exist here.

Comment: @DavideF $f'(x) = 2|x|$ actually, not that it changes your point ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you write $f(x)=|x|$ as a piecewise function, then

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      -x & x\leq 0 \\
       x & x> 0 \\
   \end{cases}
$

A function is differentiable at a point $a$ if the derivative exists at this point.

Let our point $a=0$

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a^-} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\frac{-x-(-(0))}{x-0}=-1$

and

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\frac{x-((0))}{x-0}=1$

Therefore $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

With respect to continuity, if a function is differentiable at $x=a$ then it must be continuous at $x=a$;however, continuity does not imply differentiability.

If, however, a function is not continuous at $x=a$, we can say for certain that it is not differentiable at $x=a$.